# my report is empty

Tags: crystal-reports, dataset, report, datasource, is-empty

I'm using vb net 2005. I have created a .xsd dataset with one table and a rpt report.
the dataset is PedidosDataImpresion.xsd with the table DatosPedido.
The rpt form is pedidoimpreso.rpt

this is my code:

```
Dim DatosImpresion As New PedidosDataImpresion
Dim TablaPrincipal As DataTable = DatosImpresion.DatosPedido


I = 0
TablaPrincipal.Rows.Add(1)
TablaPrincipal.Rows(I).Item("razonsocial") = Me.lblfacturacion.Text
TablaPrincipal.Rows(I).Item("calle") = Me.LblDireccion.Text
TablaPrincipal.Rows(I).Item("colonia") = Me.LblColonia.Text
TablaPrincipal.Rows(I).Item("ciudad") = Me.LblCiudad.Text
TablaPrincipal.Rows(I).Item("estado") = Me.LblEdo.Text
TablaPrincipal.Rows(I).Item("cp") = Me.LblEdo.Text
TablaPrincipal.Rows(I).Item("rfc") = Me.LblRfc.Text

PedidoImpreso.SetDataSource(DatosImpresion)
PedidoImpreso.PrintOptions.PrinterName = Impresora
PedidoImpreso.PrintToPrinter(Copias, True, 1, 1)
```

i wish to print directly to the printer with no reportviewer first

and the report comes with no data. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You had to use some third party tool to do it.

What you can do is:
Make a HTML table
Fill Data
Print table on page load (using jQuery)

In case you want report format then you will need report viewer to get itself rendered.